# How to check that a value is set on a dropdown box selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have a HTML code. The thing is that the option names contain lots of spaces until the tags are closed.

```
<SELECT NAME="auth" id="auth" Size=1 onChange="updatePageState()">
<OPTION value="0">Open System
</option>
<OPTION value="1">WEP
</option>
<OPTION value="2">WPA
</option>
<OPTION value="3">WPA2
</option>
```

I want to check that some option is selected in the dropdown box by using selenium in java. This is my code:

```
try {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementValue(((By.xpath("//select [@id='auth']/option['" + Authen + "']"))), Authen));
    System.out.println("Authentification is correct");
} catch (Exception x) {
    System.out.println("Authentification is incorrect");
    x.printStackTrace();
}
```

where "Authen" is a variable read from a file which corresponds to the options in the dropdown box.

I get the following error message:

> org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 20 seconds
>   waiting for text ('WPA2') to be the value of element located by
>   By.xpath: //select [@id='auth']/option['WPA2']

Any help on how to check if that string contains partial text? I cannot use the method *.contains* because it's of type boolean and *.textToBePresentInElementValue* needs to have the second attribute as type String.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is easier to select the webelement with a less complex @FindBy expression and then wrap the element in a Select which provides a method to get the first selected option. You then can do your comparison.

Take a look at:

https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html

Comment: I used this: 
`String selectedAuthen = new Select (driver.findElement(By.id("auth"))).getFirstSelectedOption().getText();`
and then `assertTrue (selectedAuthen.contains(Authen));` The thing is that this is a dynamic element and is not loaded instantly, so I cannot do my comparison like this

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic element"?

Comment: The webpage is using Ajax for retrieving the value from the dropdown box. It's not loaded instantly so I need to wait a bit but I don't want to use `Thread.sleep()`

Comment: I use an ExpectedCondition on the webdriver which checks for 1) document.readyState is 'complete' and 2) if there are any pending ajax requests. For the later I use an simple counter bound to a javascruipt variable that is increased with each starting ajax request and decreased with each ajax response. This works quite well for me and the apps are heavy ajaxified.

Comment: So after each user action that triggers an ajax event I use the ExpectedCondition to wait for the completed ajax response and then get the WebElement with the most up-to-date value.

Answer (score 0):

Use the xpath `containts()` function to find the element. Such as

```
//select[@id='auth']/option[contains(text(),'Open System')]
```

Comment: It does not work, I still get this error: `org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 20 seconds waiting for text ('WPA2') to be the value of element located by By.xpath: //select [@id='auth']/option[text()[contains(text()'WPA2']`

Furthermore: `Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The xpath expression '//select [@id='auth']/option[text()[contains(text()'WPA2']' cannot be evaluated or does notresult in a WebElement (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
`

Comment: Your selector is not correct. It's not the sameone as mine. You have an extra **[text()** after option which is incorrect

Comment: sorry, I used it like you said in the first comment and then I tried something else. However, I get the same error: `org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 20 seconds waiting for text ('WPA2') to be the value of element located by By.xpath: //select [@id='auth']/option[contains(text()'WPA2']`

Comment: sorry, also the comma and the parenthesis: `org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 20 seconds waiting for text ('WPA2') to be the value of element located by By.xpath: //select [@id='auth']/option[contains(text(),'WPA2')]` But still no result

Comment: I see the problem. It is actually the whitespace. My question is why do you want to match the text where you are already finding the element based on the text? Isn't that unnecessary check?

Comment: I need to check that the element is selected, and I also need to wait for it to be selected.

Comment: What I am saying is that the xpath you wrote to find the element is based off the value and there is no need to validate again. But, if you wanna test if that is selected that a different test

Comment: yes, that's what I want to test... that the value is selected in the dropdown box

Comment: even shorter with css: "#auth option:first-child" or "#auth option:contains('Open System')"

Comment: @Karthik what version of css is the second one?

Comment: Saifur, woops, i posted a jQuery selector. with css, it should be: "#auth option:first-child" or "#auth option[text*="Open System"]"

Answer (score 0):

You can check each option through this:

```
WebDriver driver;
ArrayList<String> valuesToCheck;
Select selectBox = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("auth")));
List<WebElement> boxOptions = selectBox.getOptions();
int i = 0;
ArrayList<boolean> isPresent = new ArrayList<boolean>();
for(String val : valuesToCheck)
{
    for(WebElement option : boxOptions)
    {
        selectBox.selectByIndex(i);
        if(selectBox.getFirstSelectedOption().getText().equals(valueToCheck.get(i)))
        {
            isPresent.get(0) = true;
        }
    }
    if(isPresent.get(0)!=true)
    {
        isPresent.get(0)=false;
    }
}
```

this would return an array of booleans that check if the values you were looking for were present inside of the select statement.

its a little bit of a workaround, but i think it would do the job.

Also, i couldn't find documentation so this is coming out of pure opinion and could potentially not be fact, but doesn't the value attribute supposed to specify the text? that could be your current problem.